# I want a button to appear on this line of code what shall I do?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I need a small button to appear on this line of code in my browser:

```
<%= link_to "New Article", new_article_path, :class => "new_article" %>
```

Comment: Can't you add a `button_tag`?

Comment: @PRAVIN link_to is rails helper

Comment: @Chandan- do you want CSS of it OR something else?

Comment: I want it to be in css.@Chandrakant

Answer (score 0):

`<button>This is the text of the button</button>`